# store vtk polydata as a string in python

Tags: python, vtk

I am starting with a set of vtk actors I am trying to pass the vtk polydata for each of these actors to a set of python variables (one for each actor) as a string exactly as it would be formatted in a legacy .vtk file to be used later by three.js in a ipython notebook.

I have found examples of writing .vtk files using vtkPolydataWriter but nothing that simply captures the string being written.

Any examples (especially in python) would be helpful

Here is an example of what I am starting from:

```
import vtk  

# Create source
source = vtk.vtkSphereSource()  
source.SetCenter(0, 0, 0)  
source.SetRadius(5.0)  

# Create a mapper
mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(source.GetOutputPort())

# Create an actor
actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)

# Get PolyData as String
writer = vtk.vtkPolyDataWriter()
writer.WriteToOutputStringOn()
writer.SetInputDataObject(mapper.GetInput())
string = writer.Write()
string
```

Comment: I added an example of what i have tried above

Comment: Haven't used `vtk` before but wow, that's a godawful library interface. If you can only write to a file, you could try creating a `tempfile.namedTemporaryFile`, telling it to write to that, and retreiving the string data from there. If you can give it a file-like object then `StringIO` may be of help.

Answer (score 0):

since no answer have been provided I'll drop it here in case it might be helpfull for anyone ...

```py
import vtk
 
# TODO: make mesh a vtkPolyData valid mesh

writer = vtk.vtkXMLPolyDataWriter()
writer.SetInputData(mesh)  # mesh should be a PolyData object
writer.SetDataModeToAscii()
writer.WriteToOutputStringOn()
writer.Update()
xml = writer.GetOutputString()
```

still looking for a way to reverse it so vtkReader eats a string instead of a file...

Comment: Hi Thomas did you find the way to read a string?